# Adding pseudo class in js Variable

Tags: javascript

`var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");`

Above is the current variable

Can I add a pseudo class to variable

`var modal = document.querySelector(".modal button");`

Does the above Js Var work by `.modal button`

Comment: Why not try it and see…?

Answer (score 0):

Sure! why not?

```js
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");

const btn = document.querySelector(".modal button");

console.log(modal)
console.log(btn)
```

```html
<div class="modal">
<button>Simple Button</button>
</div>
```